# Rxjs delay subscription to Subject to fire after complete

Tags: rxjs

I have created this example to demonstrate the issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-vxvmq1?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100

Basically I want to call a function (e.g. `cleanup` as in the example) when a subject is completed. The function is called by others so not subscribing to the subject's changes, rather, a subscription is there to trigger the function for the completion of the subject. The function checks if it should do extra work when the subject is completed, so it checks if the subject has stopped or not. But it seems that once `next()` is called, the function is triggered before `complete()` is called, making the function thinks the subject has not been completed yet.

I wonder if there is any way to resolve this? Calling `complete()` first then `next()` didn't help as `next()` didn't notify the subscription after the subject has completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short. It is all wrong.

Fix #1, not rxjs-idiomatic: you're subscribing wrongly: passing `onNext` callback, while you're interested in `onComplete`. There are three parameters taken by the `subscribe`: `onNext, onError, onComplete` and you are responsible for choosing the one you really need.

Fix #2, rxjs-idiomaric: you have to use `pipe(...)` along with operators defined in `rxjs/operators` (AFAIR). Note that it is easy to define your custom operator as well. So you either could use `finalize(() => ...your cleanup logic goes here)` or `Observable.create` returning finalizing logic as implementation of `unsubscribe`. Both nicely documented [here](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/) or [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/).

In addition, seems that you're misunderstanding the semantics of `rxjs`. In terms of regex, it could be defined as `next*(error|complete)`, which literally means: zero or infinitely many `next`'s followed by either `error` or `complete` (exclusive or: never both simultaneously) exactly once. So don't expect `next` to do anything after `complete` (or equally `error`) fired.